# How to call methods on Python class descriptor objects?

Tags: python, descriptor

I created a `class String()` with `__get__()`, `__set__()`, and a method `to_db()`; however, when I do `name = String()`, I can't do `self.name.to_db()` because it's calling `to_db()` on the value returned by `__get__()`, not the object "`name`".

```
class String(object):

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value:
            self.value = str(value)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = str(value)

    def to_db(self):
        return {'type':'string', 'value': self.value}

class Example(object):

    name = String()
    age = Integer()

    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def save():
        data = dict(name=self.name.to_db(), age=self.age.to_db())
        db.save(data)
```

One way to deal with this is to not call `self.name.to_db()` directly and instead set a flag in `instance` and create a conditional in `__get__()` to check for it and call `to_db()` if it's `True`, but this seems kludgy. Is there a better way?

Also, I'm new to descriptors -- what are the pros/cons of using `instance` and/or `instance.__dict__` to store state vs storing it in `self`?

Comment: How about not using descriptors for anything that requires explicit method calls on them in the first place?

Comment: Seems to me, you're trying to use descriptors in a wrong way. Here is a good descriptions: http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html, especially pay attention to property() implementation.

Comment: Why are you not using properties?

Comment: `String` descriptor object will be shared between all `Example` objects. So if you create `exp1 = Example("Example1")` and `exp2 = Example("Example2")`, then `exp1.name` and `exp2.name` will give same output `'Example2'`. Use `property` instead as per @JochenRitzel

Answer (score 8):

It's pretty easy - just have your descriptor return a subclass of string with the extra method(s) you want.

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    class TaggedString(str):
        def to_db(self):
            return {'type':'string', 'value': self}
    return TaggedString(self.value)`
```

Comment: It doesn't work completely as per my above comment. If you really want to use descriptor - make use of `instance` argument with label to get `value` per instance level.

Answer (score 1):

Descriptors are used to describe "what is it" or "how it works".

For example, we can put some restriction in the `__get__()` or the `__set__()`.

According to your question, I think you want to add your own method into `type<str>`, not to describe how to set or get the instance.

So you may use thee code below to express what you want to do.

```
class String(str):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def to_db(self):
        return {'type':'string', 'value': self.value}

ss = String('123')
print ss #123
print ss.to_db() #{'type':'string', 'value': '123'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that allows you to bypass any descriptors defined in the class:

```
class BypassableDescriptor(object):
    pass

class String(BypassableDescriptor):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value:
            self.value = str(value)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = str(value)

    def to_db(self):
        return {'type': 'string', 'value': self.value}

class Integer(BypassableDescriptor):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value:
            self.value = str(value)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = int(value)

    def to_db(self):
        return {'type': 'integer', 'value': self.value}

class BypassDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, descriptor):
        self.descriptor = descriptor

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.descriptor, name)

class AllowBypassableDescriptors(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, members):
        new_members = {}
        for name, value in members.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value, BypassableDescriptor):
                new_members['real_' + name] = BypassDescriptor(value)
        members.update(new_members)
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, members)

class Example(object):
    __metaclass__ = AllowBypassableDescriptors

    name = String()
    age  = Integer()

    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age  = age

    def save(self):
        data = dict(name = self.real_name.to_db(), age = self.real_age.to_db())
```

Note that it's not perfect - you'll always have to call `real_fieldname.method()` instead of `fieldname.method()` and you'll have to use the metaclass AllowBypassableDescriptors for all your classes which need to access this field. Then again, it's a pretty compatible solution that avoids monkey-patching the object wrapped by the descriptor.

That said, I'm not sure that descriptors are the best solution for what you're trying to do (writing to a database?).

Answer (score -1):

Inside method **to_db** you may access directly the value via

```
self.__dict__['value'] # value as key is not ideal, but that's what OP used
```

or, if you are using new style classes only,

```
object.__set__(self, name, value)
```

Since you are using magic attributes, accessing the magic `__dict__` is perfectly reasonable.

This is also referred in the documentation for `__setattr__` [1] (sorry, there is no direct reference to `__dict__` in `__set__` but it's the same problem domain)

```
If __setattr__() wants to assign to an instance attribute, it should not 
simply execute   self.name = value — this would cause a recursive call to itself. 
Instead, it should insert the value in the dictionary of instance attributes, e.g., 
self.__dict__[name] = value. For new-style classes, rather than accessing the instance 
dictionary, it should call the base class method with the same name, for example, 
object.__setattr__(self, name, value).
```

[1] http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access

Comment: This is a nasty workaround at best. I'd avoid fiddling with `__dict__`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but e = Example(name="Julie",age="21")  then e.name.to_db() says: >>> e.name.to_db()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_db'
" -- presumably because __get__ is being called first.