# Assigning Descriptor attribute outside class

Tags: python

I have a Descriptor for lazy loading from a data store that returns a default value if the data store is not available. The Descriptor works fine except for the case in which I want the default value to be an instance of a supplied class type which is the same class type in which the Descriptor is defined (needed for tree hierarchies). Ideally I would like to do

```
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

class Descriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, classType=None):
        self.classType = classType
        self.values = WeakKeyDictionary()
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print("name:", self.name)
        if instance not in self.values:
            self.values[instance] = self.classType()
        return self.values[instance]
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.values[instance] = value


class Item1(object):
    pass


class Item2(object):
    parent1 = Descriptor(Item1)
    parent2 = Descriptor(Item2)


item2 = Item2()
print(item2.parent1)
print(item2.parent2)
```

but obviously the Descriptor for parent2 cannot be passed the class that it is being defined within. So an alternative is to assign parent2 after the class has been defined:

```
class Item2(object):
    parent1 = Descriptor(Item1)


Item2.parent2 = Descriptor(Item2)
```

However, in this case the __set_name__ method does not seem to be called when creating the Constructor since the following error is given:

```
name: parent1
<__main__.Item1 object at 0x021F4890>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\setNameTest.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(item2.parent2)
  File "..\setNameTest.py", line 10, in __get__
    print("name:", self.name)
AttributeError: 'Descriptor' object has no attribute 'name'
```

What seems to work is to just assign the itemClass value to parent2 after the Descriptor is created within the class but it seems clunky to use throughout the codebase:

```
class Item2(object):
    parent1 = Descriptor(Item1)
    parent2 = Descriptor()


Item2.__dict__['parent2'].classType = Item2
```

Is there a cleaner method?

Edit 09Mar2017:
Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/6995286/1834561, this method can be cleaned up a bit by returning self from Descriptor.__get__ if instance is None, i.e.

```
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
           return self
        print("name:", self.name)
        if instance not in self.values:
            self.values[instance] = self.classType()
        return self.values[instance]
```

Now the classType can be assigned outside of the class definition by

```
Item2.parent2.classType = Item2
```

Comment: You can use a metaclass, but I'm not sure your desriptor is going to work... what are you trying to do with the `__set_name__` method?

Comment: I am using \__set_name__ to get the name that the descriptor is assigned to and using the name when interacting with the data store

Comment: sorry, this is new with Python 36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when you need to access the class itself inside the class-level scope, you have to use a *metaclass*. However, I am unfamiliar with the new `__set_name__` dunder method, and I am not able to get it to work with a metaclass. However, here is an alternative way -- the old way --. First, you have to pass `name` to your `Descriptor` `__init__`:

```
In [10]: from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
    ...:
    ...: class Descriptor(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self, name, classType=None):
    ...:         self.classType = classType
    ...:         self.values = WeakKeyDictionary()
    ...:         self.name = name
    ...:     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    ...:         print("name:", self.name)
    ...:         if instance not in self.values:
    ...:             self.values[instance] = self.classType()
    ...:         return self.values[instance]
    ...:     def __set__(self, instance, value):
    ...:         self.values[instance] = value
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: class Item1(object):
    ...:     pass
    ...:
```

Now, define your metaclass. This can probably be better encapsulated, but it gets the idea across. Again, note, I am passing the `name` to `Descriptor`:

```
In [11]: class ItemMeta(type):
    ...:     def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
    ...:         cls.parent1 = Descriptor('parent1', Item1)
    ...:         cls.parent2 = Descriptor('parent2', cls)
    ...:
    ...:
```

Finally, using Python3 syntax, we create `Item2` using the metaclass:

```
In [12]: class Item2(object, metaclass=ItemMeta):
    ...:     pass
    ...:
```

And now, it should work:

```
In [13]: x = Item2()

In [14]: x.parent1
name: parent1
Out[14]: <__main__.Item1 at 0x1104db240>

In [15]: x.parent2
name: parent2
Out[15]: <__main__.Item2 at 0x1104dbc50>
```

Comment: Nice solution. I like the metaclass keeping all of the definitions before and at  the top of the class definition, but needing to restate the attribute name is less than ideal.

Comment: @jeshep I agree, it is less than ideal. Although, on one hand, it is in line with "explicit is better than implicit". But sometimes, implicit is nice. I still hold out hope that there is some way to make the metaclass work with `__set_name__` but I just haven't played around with py36 enough. I know the way that one used to mock the functionality of `__set_name__` was by using a metaclass, but I could not successfully marry the two approaches in my attempts. There are definitely some gaps in my knowledge of the data model this revealed to me, though.